# Remove tab from UITabBar without UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

I'm using a UITabBar without a controller. I want to remove tabs from the UITabBar if certain conditions are met. For example, my UITabBar has 4 tabs set up in interface builder. If the scores module is not enabled at compile time, it should remove the scores tab.

```
// defined in IB
#define kTabScores 1 
UITabBar *_tabBar;


// in viewDidLoad
#if !INCLUDE_SCORES_SUPPORT
    // this doesn't seem to work
    [[_tabBar viewWithTag:kTagScores] removeFromSuperview];
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`items`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW8) property of the [`UITabBar`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? For instance:

```
// defined in IB
#define kTabScores 1 
UITabBar *_tabBar;


// in viewDidLoad
#if !INCLUDE_SCORES_SUPPORT
    NSMutableArray *newItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_tabBar.items];
    [newItems removeObjectAtIndex:0]; //your index here.
    [_tabBar setItems:newItems animated:YES];
#endif
```

Comment: That did the trick! One caveat to note is that it's arrayWithArray; arrayWithItems doesn't exist.